# How to make ArrayList by type like (Button) R.id.buttonId?

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

In the layout code, Button IDs are made. I need to access all the buttons and make an ArrayList, load the buttons by `findViewById()` in Java, put the Buttons in the `ArrayList`.
But it shows a `NullPointerException`.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.bqlab.themelab/com.bqlab.themelab.activity.SelectActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null
>   object reference

The cause of using this form is, I need to use setOnClickListener every buttons.

The problem is this code, And thank you to read.

```
selectTopButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.select_top_btn01));
selectTopButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.select_top_btn02));
selectTopButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.select_top_btn03));
selectTopButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.select_top_btn04));
selectTopButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.select_top_btn05));
selectTopButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.select_top_btn06));

for (int i = 0; i < selectTopButtons.size(); i++) {
        final int finalI = i;
        selectTopButtons.get(finalI).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectTopButtons.get(finalI).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.colorYellow));
                clickedButton = selectTopButtonNames.get(finalI);
                for (int i = 0; i < selectTopButtons.size(); i++) {
                    if (i == finalI)
                        break;
                    else
                        selectTopButtons.get(finalI).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.colorWhite));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The ArrayList is null... The buttons aren't the problem

Comment: So I added button by add method. Is it wrong way?

Comment: No, you didn't. `Attempt to invoke ... add() ... on a null reference`. The buttons were never added because the list doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an arraylist. Try a regular loop.

```
final Resources res = getResources();

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    // Get the numbers of the views
    String id = String.format("%02d", i);
    // Generate the R.id values
    int resId = res.getIdentifier("select_top_btn"+resId, "id", getPackageName());
    // Find the view
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(resId);
    // setup button
    final Integer iCopy = new Integer(i);
    b.setOnClickListener( ... );
}
```

Also, `clickedButton` is the same as `v`, the method parameter. You don't need to access a list to get the clicked view.

If you needed a List, you can put `List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();` before the loop, and `buttons.add(b);` within it.

Comment: clickButton is need on other class.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you might want to post a [mcve] next time you ask a question

Comment: Thank you. I understood.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an instance of the list first:

```
List<Button> selectTopButtons= new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood.

Comment: @Sinho BTW, you could also use a list with my answer.

Comment: @cricket_007 It was not the answer I wanted, but thank you to you that I got to know it new.